Is it possible to get an tbl_regression output with type II sum of squares instead of type III?
I am trying to get results in two ways: using sums of squares of types II and III. As far as I can tell, tbl_regression gets estimates output only for type III. Can I manually set the "type = II" argument and specify the function (car::Anova)?
n <- 50
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:n*2,
         1:n*2),
  time = c(rep("t_0", n*2),
            rep("t_6", n*2)),
  group = c(rep("trt", n),
                rep("ctrl", n),
                rep("trt", n),
                rep("ctrl", n)),
  value = c(rnorm(n,20,5),
            rnorm(n,20,5),
            rnorm(n,50,5),
            rnorm(n,30,5))
)
fit <- lm (value ~ group*time, df)
tbl_regression(fit,
               pvalue_fun = label_style_pvalue(digits = 3),
               show_single_row = everything(),
               method.args = list(type = "II")) %>%
  bold_p(t = 0.05, q = FALSE) %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  tab_options(row.striping.include_table_body = TRUE)

I want to learn how to manually set the output parameters of tbl_regression.
